# Simulation of rubber material attached to two objects

Tags: physics

I start my work in a blender and I have to do animation of fins for advertising, the model I received from the client, it will be attached to the foot, the movement of the leg will also move the fin (I will do it with armature), and the whole will be plunged in simulated water with mantafluid .

I have a problem now with the membrane simulation which is between two hard rails. It must be attached to these rails and move with some resistance like the real material from which it is made.

To explain it simply, I have two rails and a material between them (preview image because I can’t share the original model):

[image]

And this material should have such properties, i.e. bend like rubber:
[image]

So these two rails will move and the rubber will stick to them and its center should move like a real fin under water.

I thought to do it with “Soft Body” but I don’t know how to connect it to the rails, then I thought that maybe the “Cloth” function would work but I can’t do it here either. I will be very grateful for your help because on the Internet I could not find any guide that would show anything similar :(

Comment: does it need to be physics? why not simulate it with bones or other techniques?

Comment: With cloth simulation you can control the stiffness' tension and compression. The more rigid parts can also be Cloth but with different stiffness. To hold the membrane between two rails use vertex pinning.